# Set a form as the parent of a button programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

In an HTML page I have this button:

```
<div>

<span class="myBtn">

<input type="submit" class="myClass" value="Cancel" id="cancel" name="myName" title="none">

</span>

</div>
```

With JS, I would like to change it this way, so that the button is "surrounded" by a form:

```
<div>

<form action="myURL" method='GET'>

<span class="myBtn">

<input type="submit" class="myClass" value="Cancel" id="cancel" name="myName" title="none">

</span>

</form>

</div>
```

Is this possible? I'm looking for a simple, vanilla JS solution, no JQuery.

Comment: Note that the submit button doesn't have to be inside the form, you can associate it with a form using its [*form* attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#association-of-controls-and-forms) (a case sensitive match for the form's ID), so as long as the form is somewhere in the page, the button will submit it.

Comment: The HTML page can't be changed, it's a legacy intranet page and I must access it through an Android app webview (a very "original" case)   :-)

Comment: I was hoping that you could insert the form anywhere using script. However it seems that in some browsers at least, inserting the form and modifying the input's *form* attribute doesn't associate the input with the form. :-(  It does work if it's in the original HTML though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = 'myURL';
form.method = 'GET';
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('myBtn')[0];
var parent = span.parentElement;
form.appendChild(span);
parent.appendChild(form);
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="myBtn">
        <input type="submit" class="myClass" value="Cancel" id="cancel" name="myName" title="none"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Minor quibble, but adding the span to the form before putting it in the document may make life easier for the layout engine.

Comment: @RobG Excellent suggestion, thanks! (Took me some time to figure out I needed to capture the parent of the span first, then add the span to the form, then add the form to the parent, but eventually I got there.)